# Retrieve a property of a class as a collection

Tags: vb.net, oop, reflection, collections, vb.net-2010

I'm working on a small project and got into some troubles trying to keep it OOP.

I have a global variable:

```
Public Stations As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()
```

And 2 classess: `Station` & `Unit`:

```
Public Class Station

    Property name As String
    Property stype As String
    Property units As New Collection
End Class

Public Class unit
     Property name As String
     Property lbl As String
     Property ip As String
     Property utype As String
End Class
```

I guess you can see the hierarchy in here:

```
Collection Stations -> Object Station -> Collection Units -> Object Unit
```

There's a code which grab data from XML files and according to it adds objects to the collections above.

However , I didn't figure how can I retrieve the collection of units based on the `Stations` collection.
I tried something like this:

```
    Dim st = Stations.Item("The key of a specific object in the Stations collection")
    Dim stUnits = st.GetType().GetProperty("units")
```

But when I'm trying to retrieve the `stUnits` collection:

```
For Each unit In stUnits
```

It says that `stUnits` isn't a collection.
I am a bit confused, thanks for any help possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.
Forgot to set `st` as a station object.

```
Dim st As Station = Stations.Item("The key of a specific object in the Stations collection")
```

And then , simply:

```
Dim stUnits = st.units
```